# Maven Spring Web MVC resource not available

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

Creating a Spring MVC web app using Maven. Please find the image of the below directory structure. web.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml files. I am not able to get the required index.jsp page contents. I am new to it so, please can anybody check and let me where is the mistake ?

**Web.xml**:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">
  <display-name>MongoSample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>    
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>    
    <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" cache-period="1314000"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" cache-period="1314000"/>

    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="27017"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database  --> 
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean> 
</beans>
```

Folder directory structure:

[image: Folders Directory Structure]

Controller:

```
package com.controller;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.service.UserService;
import com.model.User;
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);

     @RequestMapping(value="/users",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
     public @ResponseBody List<User> getAllUsers() {     
      List<User> users=userService.getAllUserService();
      return users;
     }


     @RequestMapping(value="/users/archive/{id}",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
     public @ResponseBody List<User> archiveUser(@PathVariable String id) { 
         userService.archieveUserService(id);
       List<User> users=userService.getAllUserService();
      return users;
     }


     @RequestMapping(value="/users/update",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
         public @ResponseBody List<User> updateUser(@RequestBody User users) throws ParseException {    

            users.setLast_update_time(new Date());
         logger.info(":: Setting values in controller while updation in progress::"+users); 
           userService.updateUserService(users);

         return userService.getAllUserService();

     }

         @RequestMapping(value="/users/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST)
         public List<User> addUser(@RequestBody User users) throws ParseException { 
            Date date = new Date();
                users.setCreation_time(date);
                users.setLast_update_time(date);
            userService.saveUserService(users);
            return userService.getAllUserService();
         }                   
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:109)
    ... 16 more

Feb 26, 2016 1:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 26, 2016 1:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/m] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 26, 2016 1:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 26, 2016 1:14:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:993)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: is there index.jsp inside of jsp folder?

Comment: In a SpringMVC application it is typical to use a controller (java class with @Controller annotation) to hande request and name the jsp that should do the html rendering. Do you have such an controller, and if you haven one, then please post it (especial the returned view name, and the url to which the controller is mapped) as well as the url you request is relevant for your question.

Comment: @Ralph, it is a Rest Controller. The initial loading page is not available.

Comment: are you getting 404 error?

Comment: can you paste that exception

Comment: @NallaSrinivas , yes I am getting 404 error. I have added the exception.

Comment: have you checked your lib availble in lib folder at the time starting the server

Comment: @NallaSrinivas I have check the deployment assembly for dependencies. I am using maven fro dependency management.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104621/discussion-between-nalla-srinivas-and-harshit).

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you need a controller (method) to render the jsp, this could be an normal "hand" written controller, or some somehting like this

```
<view-controller path="index.html*" view-name="index"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, I figured out the problem and I resolved this, but now I am getting some exceptions. Will try  to resolve the same.

Comment: @Harshit: please do not change the scope of questions, instead rise a new one.